# .htaccess RewriteRule to affect directories only / SPA HTML5 pushState friendly URLs

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently moved to Media Temple and it broke all of my wonderful RewriteRules by sending full paths instead of relative paths so I've needed to make significant changes to my `mod_rewrite`

As they stand:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^www/ index.php [L]
```

My folder and URL structure, where real folders are in bold:

**/**

**/www**

/www/experiences

/www/experiences/project-slug-that-js-handles

**/www/project-files-folder/css, etc**

**/assets/js, css, etc.**

---

**/www** and **/www/experiences/project-slug-that-js-handles** rewrite to /index.php successfully, but the assets being request from /www/experiences/project-slug-that-js-handles are also being rewritten to /index.php and this is the problem.

So is it possible to tell a RewriteRule to only affect folders in a directory or do I need better conditions/rules all together?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your last rule is culprit and is causing css/js loading errors:

```
RewriteRule ^www/ index.php [L]
```

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^www/?$ index.php [L,NC]
```

`^www/?$` will match only `/www/` instead of everything inside `/www/`